# Git version of checkout? Clone not doing what I want

Tags: git

I'm new to Git but have used SVN a great deal.  I've been reading up on Git as we are moving that direction for some work projects.

I've been tasked with setting up the repositories and helping others get access to them.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

I have a working repository configured on a remote server (our Git server).  I was able to use the following command on my local machine:

```
git clone <url to remote repo>
```

I then started modifying and committing.  Everything has worked great.

Now I have another user, on another machine, who I want to have access to the repository.  I'd like to have the ability for him to do a basic checkout and begin editing the files himself.  How do I manage this in Git?  Does he need to create a working branch for himself?

I tried to use the same clone command I used and it gave him an "empty" directory.  After further investigation I noticed I had a "master" copy which was not what I wanted.  I read up on `clone` I realized this is not what I intended.  What did I get when I ran the `clone` command for myself (a branch or something else)?

I've read a lot of tutorials, crash courses for people transitioning from SVN and several posts on this site.  I just haven't quite been able to get things working.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I don't think people are being jerks.  It's a legitimate question (and that's why I'm helping out!), but (a) a lot of the material is covered explicitly in the standard documentation, and (b) the question is lacking a number of important details (like, the exactly sequence of commands you ran in each location, exactly how your created the remote repository, etc).  Don't get mad at people for the downvotes (after all, nobody voted to close it).  Use it as a learning experience to write better questions in the future.

Comment: I don't know if I'd downvote this, but you really should google 'example git workflow' or something like that, and read through it. It's conceptually a lot different than SVN, and it seems like you're using it as though it's exactly the same (with some new command names)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What did I get when I ran the clone command for myself (a branch or something else)?

When you run `clone`, you are getting yourself a complete copy of the repository (including the entire history), *and* you are getting yourself a checked-out working copy.  The working copy is what you're editing; the repository is everything inside the `.git` directory.

If you are collaborating with someone else, you should both run the same `git clone` command.  When you want to make changes you have committed visible to your collaborator, you run `git push` to send the changes back to the remote repository, and your collaborator runs `git pull` to update her local repository and working copy.

The [distributed workflows](http://book.git-scm.com/3_distributed_workflows.html) section of the Git Book has some good reading on this topic.

Comment: I created a clone for the other user and went into the working directory and ran `git pull` and received the following error message: `Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref 'master'
from the remote, but no such ref was fetched.`

Comment: Wait...I just realized I may not have pushed my changes correctly.  Commit does not actually update the remote server?  How can I do this?  I ran `git push` and received the following error: `No refs in common and none specified; doing nothing.
Perhaps you should specify a branch such as 'master'.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`

Comment: Read the document I linked to.  `git commit` does not update the remote repository; this is not Subversion.  You are operating entirely in your local repository until you run `git push`.  If you are starting with an empty remote repository, then you have no refs in common, so the first time you push you need to provide an explicit reference, like this: `git push origin master`, which means "push my `master` branch to the `master` branch on the remote named `origin`".

Comment: ...after this, simply running `git push` by itself will generally do the right thing.

Comment: Yes, this exactly where my problem was - getting to the first rung of the latter.  Unfortunately I wasn't reading the "public repository" section.  Thank you!

Comment: Sure.  If this did solve your problem it would be great if you could mark it as accepted. Thanks!